# Paypal IPN send but web server down

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am using express checkout method for recurring payment and my webserver was down for 2 days and paypal has send IPN but updates to my DB was not done due to server down.

Is there any way I can resend that IPN or fetch that transaction.
I have tried GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails, GetTransactionDetails API call but not getting exact same parameters.

can i set multiple URL for paypal IPN? or any other ways.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PayPal's system will automatically re-send those, actually.  If the server is back up you should notice that the ones you missed are getting re-sent.  That said, if it re-sends a bunch of times and it keeps failing they could put them on a much longer queue, so it you may find that another day or two it would automatically re-send the ones you missed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew yes i have noticed that in IPN history page there is dropdown with delivery status: Failed, Sent, Disabled, Retrying Queued so IPN can be in either status. Paypal will resend those when server up thanks a lot Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The IPN can be resent from you PayPal account. Login to you PayPal account and mouseover on the "History" in the navigation bar, click the "IPN history" in the pull down menu, then you can review and resend the IPNs in the last 28 days.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question but my problem is like I want to make this process automated instead of manual. Might be in future client change the password of paypal he won't share payment passwords.